# give wpf application with database to client

Tags: wpf, deployment, client

I have a wpf application that is connected to my database which was created in microsoft SQL server Management using this:

```
private SqlConnection connect()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Server=LAPTOP-1B0SDCU1 ;Database=project;User ID=sa;Password=123;Trusted_Connection=true;Integrated Security=false";
            return con;
        }
```

and added my data in a table called material as such

```
 private void insertdata(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
                connect();
                con.Open();
                string material = materialfield.Text;


                string saved = "INSERT INTO materialtable(material) VALUES ('" + material + "')";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(saved, con);
                com.ExecuteReader();
                viewdetails();
                MessageBox.Show("record is added");
            

        }
```

here my server is my own computer. Now I want to give this application to my client along with the database so that they can add details into the database and those details will only be stored on their laptop, but I do not know how to. Can someone please help.

Comment: Do you intend for each client to have their own DB on their pc? Why not have a separate Server side application? And if so, does your installation set up MSSQL also?

Comment: yes I intend to have client to have their own database.  what do you mean by having separate server side?

Comment: Usually the user has several PCs connected to a remote PC hosting the server side application/process/service. And the server side has the DB set up on its side, so each user that wants to change something on the DB and have other users see the changes can do so. If all you want is for the client to have some values saved locally, consider either saving those values to a file, or using local DB, like SQLite for example.

Comment: how do i save those values to a file? also if i do then would i be able to give an updated version (same database name and table just added more in the application) of the application without having it disturb the previous data added to the DB? I've added data as show above (edited my question)

Comment: The file could be either xml file/json file/your own type of plain text file with your own extension name kind of file. And it could be encrypted or not. There are really a lot of options out there, depending on your needs. It sounds to me you need to read more about these subjects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/fileaccess/   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/